# How to store a calculated value in new column by iterating through each row in a dataframe in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The dataframe I am working with looks like this:

```
  vid2               FStart FEnd cap2                                               VDuration  COS  cap1
0 -_aaMGK6GGw_57_61  0      3    A man grabbed a boy from his collar and threw ...  4          2    A man and woman are yelling at a young boy and...
1 -_aaMGK6GGw_57_61  3      4    A lady is waking up a man lying on a chair and...  4          2    A man and woman are yelling at a young boy and...
2 -_hbPLsZvvo_5_8    0      1    A white dog is barking and a caption is writte...  3          2    a dog barking and cooking with her master in t...
  ...                ...    ...  ...                                                ...        ...  ...
```

I am trying to calculate a similarity score between the two columns *cap1* and *cap2*. However, I want to create a new column *FSim* that stores this similarity score for each row.

The code I have implemented till now is:

```
#The function that calculates the similarity score
def get_cosine_similarity(feature_vec_1, feature_vec_2):    
    return cosine_similarity(feature_vec_1.reshape(1, -1), feature_vec_2.reshape(1, -1))[0][0]


for i, row in merged.iterrows():
    captions = []
    captions.append(row['cap1'])
    captions.append(row['cap2'])

    for c in range(len(captions)):
        captions[c] = pre_process(captions[c])
        captions[c] = lemmatize_sentence(captions[c])

    feature_vectors = tfidf_vectorizer.transform(captions)

    fsims = get_cosine_similarity(feature_vectors[0], feature_vectors[1])
    merged['fsim'] = fsim
```

But I am getting the same similarity scored stored for each row like this:

```
       fsim  
0  0.054464  
1  0.054464  
2  0.054464  
3  0.054464  
4  0.054464
```

Same value for all the rows.

How to get properly stored the score for each row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this ? (I'm assuming the DataFrame you have first is `merged`)

```
def preproc_and_lemmatize(x):
  v1 = pre_process(x)
  return lemmatize_sentence(v1)

def calc_sim(x, y):
  x2 = preproc_and_lemmatize(x)
  y2 = preproc_and_lemmatize(y)
  feature_vectors = tfidf_vectorize.transform([x2, y2])
  return get_cosine_similarity(feature_vectors[0], feature_vectors[1])

merged['fsim'] = [
  calc_sim(x, y) for x, y in zip(merged['cap1'], merged['cap2'])
]
```

If you prefer to less edit, this will work.

```
merged["fsim"] = 0
for i, row in merged.iterrows():
    captions = []
    captions.append(row['cap1'])
    captions.append(row['cap2'])

    for c in range(len(captions)):
        captions[c] = pre_process(captions[c])
        captions[c] = lemmatize_sentence(captions[c])

    feature_vectors = tfidf_vectorizer.transform(captions)

    fsims = get_cosine_similarity(feature_vectors[0], feature_vectors[1])
    merged['fsim'].iloc[i] = fsims
```

Comment: In original code, you assign a scalar `fsim` to a column of `merged`. By that, Pandas makes a sequence having length of len(merged) with one value `fsim`, as you see. Maybe, the value `0.054464` you get is the similarity of the last row. (Because that is last calculated `fsim`)